# Chrome Extension: extracting keywords from tab not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension to store links in a similar way that Delicious does it. As a part of my extension I want to save the keywords of the link that I'm storing. In order to get this keywords I use the following function:

```
EXT.get_keywords = function (tab) {
var keywords = [];

    if(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"js/keywords.js"},
            (function(keywords) {
                return function (res) {
                    var kw_str = res && res[0];
                    if (kw_str) {
                        keywords.push.apply(keywords, kw_str.split(","));
                    }
                }
            })(keywords));
    }
    console.log(keywords);
    return keywords;
}
```

The content of "js/keywords.js" file is the following:

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta'),
    i = 0,
    result = "";

for (i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    if (metas[i].getAttribute("name") === "keywords") {
        result = metas[i].getAttribute("content");
        break;
    }
}
result;
```

The "js/keywords.js" script works pretty well and the callback function gets the content string from the keywords tag if it exists but when after the callback is executed, the keywords variables always is `[]`. Any idea?

PS: It's quite weird because if I execute the script with a breakpoint at the `console.log(keywords)` line it works but if the breakpoint is not present it doesn't :S.

Comment: "Weird" ? Do you mean asynchronous ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the asynchronous nature of **chrome.tabs.executeScript()**. You can't return the keywords from your `get_keywords` function - actually you **can** return an empty `keywords` array, but it won't be populated until after the function has exited.
(Most **chrome.*** APIs are asynchronous, so you have to adapt your whole extension "style" to conform to this.)

**So, what happens ?**

This is the execution order:

1. The empty `keywords` array is initialized (`var keywords = [];`).
2. `executeScript` is called initiating some asunchrosous stuff in the background.
3. `(function(keywords) {...})(keywords)` is called, returning and registering a callback (which is bound to the still empty `keywords` array). The callback will be called once every injection and execution is over.
4. `executeScript` returns (note that no callback is executed yet - asunchronously still doing stuff in the background, i.e. injecting and executing JS).
5. `console.log(keywords);` logs the (still empty) `keywords` array.
6. The still empty `keywords` array is returned (`return keywords;`).
7. The asynchronous injecting/executing is over and the callback is called, populating the `keywords` array.

If you activate a breakpoint, then there is time for the injection/execution to complete before step 5 is reached, so the `keywords` array is populated before returning it.

---

A sample extension that demonstrates this:

In **background.js**, the `keywords` array is logged twice: once before it is returned by `getKeywords()` and once after it is populated in the callback. As you can see the logging in callback is executed **after** `getKeywords()` has returned an empty array.

**content.js:**

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName("meta");
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    var meta = metas[i];
    if (meta.name && (meta.name.toLowerCase() === "keywords")) {
        result = meta.content;
        break;
    }
}
result;
```

**background.js:**

```
function getKeywords(tab) {
    var keywords = [];

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
            tab.id,
            { file: "/fg/content.js" },
            (function(keywords) {
                return function(resultArr) {
                    if (!chrome.runtime.lastError && resultArr[0]) {
                        keywords.push.apply(keywords, resultArr[0].split(","));
                    }
                    console.log("After: ", keywords);
                }
            })(keywords));
    console.log("Before: ", keywords);
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getKeywords);
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name":    "Test Extension",
    "version": "0.0",

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,
        "scripts": ["./bg/background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Test Extension"
    },

    "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```